# Can't get collections after res.send() on FireFunctions

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

After I updated firebase-admin and firebase-functions to their latest versions (8.12.1 from 8.0.0 & 3.6.1 from 3.1.0 respectively) querying collections to Firestore after sending a response suddenly stopped working, so my code basically looks like this:

```
export const saveData = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {

  // Doing some stuff here...

  res.send({data: cards});

  // Some other logic I need to perform here after sending response to avoid more delays
  db.collection(path).get().then(snapShot => {
    // This code simply doesn't get excuted and no error is triggered
  }).catch(err => console.log(err))
}
```

If I move the res.send inside the collection query callback then it is executed, I have done some research but can't find why it is not working anymore, so hopefully someone can point me out the solution or a workaround, since waiting for all that processes to run will delay the response too much.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> If I move the res.send inside the collection query callback then it is executed

This is exactly what you're supposed to do.  I would never expect the code you're showing now to work correct.

In Cloud Functions HTTP triggers, sending the response is the very last thing you should do.  As stated in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions), sending the response terminates the function and shuts everything down.  It's not possible to have a function continue to execute after you send a response.  If you were seeing different behavior in the past, it was probably due to a race condition.